# Javascript の forEach のエラー

Tags: javascript, node.js

nodejs を 使ったAPIを作っています。

```
const _     = require('lodash');    
const func  = require('./func');
const items = [item1, item2, ....];
const data  = {};

const main = async () => {

    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    　　_.assign(data, {
      　　　[items[i]]: await func.getData(items[i])
      　});
    }

    keywords.forEach( (item, index, self)  => {
        _.assign(data, {
            [item]: await func.getData(item)
        });
    });

    console.log(data);

};

main();
```

上記のような、あるitemの配列についてループを回す際に、forEachの場合のみ以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
[item]: await func.getData(item, 30)
              ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

これは何が原因なのでしょうか？
funcは、別ファイルで関数群を定義し、async function をexportしています。

Answer (score 1):

forEachのcallbackに対して `async` が必要になるようですね。

```js
keywords.forEach( async (item, index, self)  => {}
```

Comment: 理解しました！
ありがとうございます。

stack overflow 利用経験がまったくなく返信が遅れてしまい申し訳ございません。